# Onde colocar novos pacotes em um projeto maven no eclipse?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, eclipse, maven

Estou aprendendo a usar JPA com Maven no Eclipse, e pretendo usar o padrão de projetos MVC, quando crio o projeto, tenho a seguinte visão: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois bem, queria saber em qual pasta aí eu devo criar novos pacotes Model, View, Controller, etc. Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de saber onde você deve colocar quais coisas dentro do projeto, eu sugiro uma breve leitura no [Getting Started do Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html). Isso vai ajudar a você compreender vários detalhes e convenções utilizadas em um projeto Maven, para que você não entenda a dinâmica da ferramenta, e não que "deve ser assim porque alguém me disse apenas".

A sua dúvida está relacionada com a estrutura padrão de pacotes utilizada pelo Maven, e para que serve cada um deles, esta convenção pode ser encontrada na parte de [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) da documentação:

[image: Standard Directory Layout da documentação do Maven]

No seu caso, pacotes e código fonte relacionados a aplicação devem ser colocados em `src/main/java` e `src/main/resources`.